# How to continuously monitor the directory using dnotify /inotify command

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am new to dnotify/inotify command. Can any one help me how to write a script such that it continuously monitors a directory and indicates that there is some change or modification to it.

Comment: You can find another way to watch a folder with Docker : [https://stackoverflow.com/a/74748767/20737554](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74748767/20737554)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Inotify itself is a kernel module accesible via calls from e.g. a C program.

https://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify

There is an application suite called inotify-tools, which contains:

> inotifywait - wait for changes to files using inotify
>
> http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait

and

> inotifywatch - gather filesystem access statistics using inotify
>
> http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywatch

You can use inotify directly from command line, e.g. like this to continuously monitor for all changes under home directory (may generate lots of output):

```
inotifywait -r -m $HOME
```

And here is a script that monitors continuously and reacts to Apache log activity, copied from the man file of inotifywait:

```
#!/bin/sh
while inotifywait -e modify /var/log/messages; do
  if tail -n1 /var/log/messages | grep httpd; then
    kdialog --msgbox "Apache needs love!"
  fi
done
```

Comment: The provided example doesn't actually monitor "continuously" as stated on the question. It exits on the first event. In practice some events may be missed while the inner part of the `do` is being executed.

Comment: Not only can they be missed like @Unode said, but also the initialization is taking place each time a change happens, so it's not an efficient method.

Comment: To clarify, @Unode and Wernight's comments apply only to the last example in the post (the script to react to Apache log events).

Answer (score 16):

Below is what I use to see operations on an individual file.  "-m" causes monitoring vs. exit after just one event.  To get timestamps, you need at least 3.13 version of inotify-tools, but if that is not important (or not available on your OS or hard to update to) you can skip the timefmt and format options.  "cat /etc/resolv.conf" in another shell leads to the results below:

```
$ inotifywait -m --timefmt '%H:%M' --format '%T %w %e %f' /etc/resolv.conf

Setting up watches.  
Watches established.
12:49 /etc/resolv.conf OPEN 
12:49 /etc/resolv.conf ACCESS 
12:49 /etc/resolv.conf CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE
```

inotifywait has options for monitoring directories as well, so check the manpage.  Add -r for recursive to monitor children of a dir.

Here's an example with the commands I typed in a different window shown with "->" prefix:

```
$ inotifywait -mr --timefmt '%H:%M' --format '%T %w %e %f' /home/acarwile/tmpdir
Setting up watches.  Beware: since -r was given, this may take a while!
Watches established.

-> cd into directory, no info
-> ls in directory
13:15 /home/acarwile/tmpdir/ OPEN,ISDIR 
13:15 /home/acarwile/tmpdir/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE,ISDIR 

-> touch newfile
13:16 /home/acarwile/tmpdir/ CREATE newfile
13:16 /home/acarwile/tmpdir/ OPEN newfile
13:16 /home/acarwile/tmpdir/ ATTRIB newfile
13:16 /home/acarwile/tmpdir/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE newfile

-> mv newfile renamedfile
13:16 /home/acarwile/tmpdir/ MOVED_FROM newfile
13:16 /home/acarwile/tmpdir/ MOVED_TO renamedfile

-> echo hello >renamedfile
13:16 /home/acarwile/tmpdir/ MODIFY renamedfile
13:16 /home/acarwile/tmpdir/ OPEN renamedfile
13:16 /home/acarwile/tmpdir/ MODIFY renamedfile
13:16 /home/acarwile/tmpdir/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE renamedfile

-> touch renamedfile
13:17 /home/acarwile/tmpdir/ OPEN renamedfile
13:17 /home/acarwile/tmpdir/ ATTRIB renamedfile
13:17 /home/acarwile/tmpdir/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE renamedfile

-> rm renamedfile
13:17 /home/acarwile/tmpdir/ DELETE renamedfile

-> cd ..; rmdir tmpdir
13:17 /home/acarwile/tmpdir/ DELETE_SELF
```

After the above, I tried to remake the tmpdir ("mkdir tmpdir") but got no output from that. The new tmpdir is not the same directory as the old tmpdir.  Time to just ^C and stop itnotifywait.

Answer (score 4):

As I said on https://superuser.com/a/747574/28782, I made a helper script that uses *inotifywait* without some of its direct limitations:  [**inotifyexec**](https://gist.github.com/wernight/11401031)

Usage example (supposing you've added it in your system path as executable):

```
inotifyexec "echo test" -r .
```