# Run bash command when specific entry found in syslog

Tags: bash, cron, tail, syslog

I have a linux box that occasionally puts an error in the syslog.  That error indicates a critical problem with the system.  I'm working on resolving the root of the problem.  However, I'd like a good bandaid until I get it fixed.  I've thought about running a cron job every minute that checks for the error in the syslog.  That might work but it could potentially leave the system in a bad state for close to a full minute.  This is the error:

```
 action frame to ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I'm wondering if it would make sense to run a script on startup.  That script would somehow tail -F the syslog and would run the corrective script when it finds the error message.  Is this a reasonable idea or is there a better solution.  If this is reasonable then how do I tail the syslog?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566569/how-to-continuosly-monitor-the-directory-using-dnotify-inotify-command Take a look at the answer in this post, it even has a little script that might fit your needs.

Comment: Can you not configure your syslog to also use a named pipe or a script like `^program-to-execute;template`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a typical linux box with rsyslog as the system logging daemon, then you can use a rsyslog filter and the omprog module to trigger some arbitrary command when you get a match: http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/omprog.html