# run script when chrony steps clock

Tags: linux, systemd, chrony

I need to start a certain service **after** system clock was correctly stepped by crony.

System time is maintained by chrony (`chronyd (chrony) version 3.5 (+CMDMON +NTP +REFCLOCK +RTC -PRIVDROP -SCFILTER -SIGND +ASYNCDNS -SECHASH +IPV6 -DEBUG)`).

Chrony setup, if relevant, is:

```
server 192.168.100.1 trust minpoll 2 maxpoll 4 polltarget 30
refclock PPS /dev/pps0 refid KPPS trust lock GNSS maxdispersion 3 poll 2
refclock SOCK /var/run/chrony.sock refid GNSS maxdispersion 0.2 noselect
makestep 0.1 -1
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/drift
rtcsync
```

example of a "normal, tracking status" is:

```
/ # chronyc tracking
Reference ID    : C0A86401 (192.168.100.1)
Stratum         : 2
Ref time (UTC)  : Wed Dec 01 11:52:08 2021
System time     : 0.000004254 seconds fast of NTP time
Last offset     : +0.000000371 seconds
RMS offset      : 0.000011254 seconds
Frequency       : 17.761 ppm fast
Residual freq   : +0.001 ppm
Skew            : 0.185 ppm
Root delay      : 0.000536977 seconds
Root dispersion : 0.000051758 seconds
Update interval : 16.2 seconds
Leap status     : Normal
```

while "unsynchronized" (initial) status is:

```
/ # chronyc tracking
Reference ID    : 00000000 ()
Stratum         : 0
Ref time (UTC)  : Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970
System time     : 0.000000000 seconds fast of NTP time
Last offset     : +0.000000000 seconds
RMS offset      : 0.000000000 seconds
Frequency       : 0.000 ppm slow
Residual freq   : +0.000 ppm
Skew            : 0.000 ppm
Root delay      : 1.000000000 seconds
Root dispersion : 1.000000000 seconds
Update interval : 0.0 seconds
Leap status     : Not synchronised
```

I seem to remember crony can call a script whenever stratus level changes, but I was unable to find references.

In any case:
Is there any way to instruct crony to run a script/program or otherwise send some signal whenever acquires/loses tracking with a valid server?

I am currently relying on a rather ugly: `while chronyc tracking | grep -q "Not synchronised"; do sleep 1; done` but a proactive signalling by `chronyd` would be preferred.

Details:

- System is a (relatively) small IoT device running Linux (Yocto)
- It has no RTC (it always starts with clock set to Epoch).
- System has no connection to the Internet (initially).
- System has connection to a device having a GNSS
  receiver and correct time is derived from there.
- There may be a (sometimes 'very') long time before GNSS acquires a fix and thus can propagate time.
- At a certain point chrony finally gets the right time
  and steps system clock. After this is done I need to start a service
  (or run a script or whatever).
- I am currently polling `chronyc tracking` and parsing status, but that is not really nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking to do the same and came up empty-handed.

I did, however, find `chronyc waitsync`, which appears to be a built-in way to do the polling, without the need to parse and sleep explicitly.  This works well enough for my case, since I only need to delay a single start-up action.

The existence of this command also *hints* (albeit by no means proves) that direct triggering may not be supported.  If triggering is a hard requirement, `rsyslogd` [can](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87223/rsyslog-execute-script-on-matching-log-event) [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396395/run-bash-command-when-specific-entry-found-in-syslog).

---

BTW, one can only admire the enthusiasm of systemd fans, spreading the love even when their purported answer is obviously and completely irrelevant.

Clearly, the target system does NOT use `systemd`.  The question is about `chronyd`, **not** about [`systemd-timesyncd`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/systemd-timesyncd.service.8.html), while `systemd-time-wait-sync.service` applies only to the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to investigate `systemd-time-wait-sync.service` in [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/systemd-time-wait-sync.8.html).

The suggested technique is to use `systemd` service unit that waits for `systemd-time-wait-sync.service` to synchronize kernel clock.

Using `after` command in the service unit file or pipe.
These technique are described [here](https://blog.debiania.in.ua/posts/2020-11-27-howto-delay-a-systemd-service-until-the-clock-is-synchronized.html) and [here](https://sleeplessbeastie.eu/2020/03/02/how-to-start-service-after-the-system-time-has-been-synchronized/).