# tail-like continuous ls (file list)

Tags: linux, shell, ls

I am monitoring the new files created in a folder in linux. Every now and then I issue an "ls -ltr" in it. But I wish there was a program/script that would automatically print it, and only the latest entries. I did a short while loop to list it, but it would repeat the entries that were not new and it would keep my screen rolling up when there were no new files. I've learned about "watch", which does show what I want and refreshes every N seconds, but I don't want a ncurses interface, I'm looking for something like tail:

- continuous
- shows only the new stuff
- prints in my terminal, so I can run it in the background and do other things and see the output every now and then getting mixed with whatever I'm doing :D

Summarizing: get the input, compare to a previous input, output only what is new.
Something that do that doesn't sound like such an odd tool, I can see it being used for other situations also, so I would expect it to already exist, but I couldn't find anything. Suggestions?

Comment: What distribution are you running?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to continuosly monitor the directory using dnotify /inotify command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566569/how-to-continuosly-monitor-the-directory-using-dnotify-inotify-command)

Comment: I'm running peppermint. I'm looking into 'inotify', I had never heard of it, put apparently it doesn't do what I want, just possibly helps me program a script to do it.

Comment: @msb certainly will, look at the second (lowvoted) answer there. It works out-of-box on my ubuntu box (sudo apt-get install inotify-tools)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have access to `inotifywait` (available from the inotify-tools package if you are on Debian/Ubuntu) you could write a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

WATCH=/tmp

inotifywait -q -m -e create --format %f $WATCH | while read event
do
    ls -ltr $WATCH/$event
done
```

This is a one-liner that won't give you the same information that `ls` does, but it will print out the filename:

```
inotifywait -q -m -e create --format %w%f /some/directory
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I made it a script and I'm getting $WATCH as a parameter. Thanks!

Comment: Just as an additional comment, the script lists all the new files but the filesize is usually zero, and that's because the ls is executed after the file is created but before its content is added. I added a usleep before the ls and now all is perfect. :-) Can you (or me) add that to your answer?

Comment: Does changing the `-e create` to `-e close_write` fix that?

Comment: :o yes it does! amazing this inotify thing, I'll definitely learn more about it. thanks again. :)

Answer (score 52):

You can use the very handy command `watch`

```
watch -n 10 "ls -ltr"
```

And you will get a `ls` every 10 seconds.

And if you add a `tail -10` you will only get the 10 newest.

```
watch -n 10 "ls -ltr|tail -10"
```

Comment: This will omit files where the creator changes the file's times to zeroes very shortly after ceation.

Comment: as mentioned in my original question, watch is not exactly what I want, since it will repeat the last files if there aren't enough new files, AND it has a ncurses interface. :-/

Comment: Oh, sorry - I missed your mention of curses in my excitment to answer. I use watch a lot.

Answer (score -1):

This works in `cygwin` and `Linux`. Some of the previous solutions which write a file will cause the disk to thrash.

This script does not have that problem:

```
SIG=1
SIG0=SIG
while [ $SIG != 0 ] ; do
 while [ $SIG = $SIG0 ] ; do
   SIG=`ls -1 | md5sum | cut -c1-32`
   sleep 10
 done
 SIG0=$SIG
 ls -lrt | tail -n 1
done
```